# How to wait until second button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

I have a bunch of buttons, and some terms assigned to them. I want user to connect them by their meaning. Anyway, I need when a user press a button, nothing to happen, just maybe to set a color to it, and wait until he press another one, and then to take some action(in my case to compare the terms in setText of the buttons). Again, when he press next button nothing to happen until he press 4th button and so on. How can I do that? I've done all the job until this part, I've imported database, assign text to my buttons and so on.

EDIT:

OK, here it is like Stephan asked. I use one onClickListener for all buttons. I assigned them a tag (correct I hope...I used same tags for correct pairs), I will use it later to check for correct answer (still learing that). I set the button to change it's color when pressed, and now I need it to wait until I press some other button from ArrayList labelB. If I press a button from labelA group of buttons, I want nothing to happen, only to change color. Maybe you guys think "wow this is so simple and lame" but it's pretty much complicated for me now. :)

```
public class Game extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


    // labelForButton and tagForButton
       class MyStruct {
       public MyStruct (String lab, String t){
        label = lab;
        tag = t;
    }
       private String label;
       private String tag;
       }

       final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         Button button = (Button)v;
         button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

            }
     };

Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);


a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
        a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA2);
        a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA3);
        a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA4);
        a5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA5);
        a6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA6);
        a7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA7);
        a8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA8);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bB8);

nextQuestion();
}

public void nextQuestion() {

        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{

            mDbHelper.open(); 

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsA = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();
            ArrayList<MyStruct> labelsB = new ArrayList<MyStruct>();

            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(2), "1"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(3), "1"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(4), "2"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(5), "2"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(6), "3"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(7), "3"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(8), "4"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(9), "4"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(10), "5"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(11), "5"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(12), "6"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(13), "6"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(14), "7"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(15), "7"));
            labelsA.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(16), "8"));
            labelsB.add(new MyStruct(c.getString(17), "8"));

            Collections.shuffle(labelsA);
            Collections.shuffle(labelsB);

            pitanje.setText(c.getString(1));

            a1.setText(labelsA.get(0).label);
            a1.setTag(labelsA.get(0).tag);
            a1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b1.setText(labelsB.get(0).label);
            b1.setTag(labelsB.get(0).tag);
            b1.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a2.setText(labelsA.get(1).label);
            a2.setTag(labelsA.get(1).tag);
            a2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b2.setText(labelsB.get(1).label);
            b2.setTag(labelsB.get(1).tag);
            b2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a3.setText(labelsA.get(2).label);
            a3.setTag(labelsA.get(2).tag);
            a3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b3.setText(labelsB.get(2).label);
            b3.setTag(labelsB.get(2).tag);
            b3.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a4.setText(labelsA.get(3).label);
            a4.setTag(labelsA.get(3).tag);
            a4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b4.setText(labelsB.get(3).label);
            b4.setTag(labelsB.get(3).tag);
            b4.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a5.setText(labelsA.get(4).label);
            a5.setTag(labelsA.get(4).tag);
            a5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b5.setText(labelsB.get(4).label);
            b5.setTag(labelsB.get(4).tag);
            b5.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a6.setText(labelsA.get(5).label);
            a6.setTag(labelsA.get(5).tag);
            a6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b6.setText(labelsB.get(5).label);
            b6.setTag(labelsB.get(5).tag);
            b6.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a7.setText(labelsA.get(6).label);
            a7.setTag(labelsA.get(6).tag);
            a7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b7.setText(labelsB.get(6).label);
            b7.setTag(labelsB.get(6).tag);
            b7.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            a8.setText(labelsA.get(7).label);
            a8.setTag(labelsA.get(7).tag);
            a8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            b8.setText(labelsB.get(7).label);
            b8.setTag(labelsB.get(7).tag);
            b8.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        }


        finally{
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Enable and disable buttons based on their business rules as you provided above..

Comment: can't you use some flags? change flag value on button click and when on another button take appropriate action based on that flag.

Comment: Do the first part, change the color of the button when it gets clicked. If you get stuck doing the second part, post your code here, including the layout file, and we can help you get unstuck. Hopefully, you'll have named the buttons and the field in a such a way that it will be obvious to us what they're supposed to do.

Comment: you havn't tried anything yet and what you are asking is just logic which exactly you need to use your own !!

Comment: @Pragnani, I need all of them to be enabled at the start, cause I randomly setText to all buttons and user needs to connect right ones. anuragsn7 can you post some code, I am new in java world, and still learing, so if can spare some time to give me an example with some code I would appreciate it. Stephan, OK I will do that right away, and post my code below.

Comment: @Stephan...Here you go mate, I edited my question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8;
//private boolean mShouldTakeAction; does not need this anymore
private Button mDisableButton;
.......
.......
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

     // We are going to disable button so no need to make it yellow
     //Button button = (Button)v;
     //button.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
     if (mDisableButton == null)
     {

           mDisableButton = (Button) v;
           v.setEnabled(false);
     }
     else
     {
          mDisableButton.setEnabled(true);
          mDisableButton = null;
          // do what ever you want here that is compare the terms
     }



        }
 };
```

Comment: I did not quite undestand this. Sorry, I'm a bit of a rookie in all this. Can you be more specific?

Comment: In your code that handle the button click, that is your button listener (I do not how you implement it: post your code) put this line if(mShouldTakeAction) { mShoudTakeAction = false; // next line is code to perform whatever you want } else {mShouldTakeAction = true}

Comment: OK, i'll try it. Will this code "wait" until I press the next button?

Comment: Yes, if buttons are clicked odd number of time, nothing happens it just set the mShouldTakeAction flag. If even then it will process the code inside the if.

Comment: But I will still have the problem of clicking buttons labeled with A. Or B. Your solution will solve me a problem if a user clicks once on an A buttons and next time on a B button. But what if he click on an A, and then again on an A button?

Comment: Just save the  pressed  button.  Disable. It   and   enable it when next  button. Is. Press

Comment: No, I can't find a way to do it. I just don't have an idea how to compare tags. I understand what you are saying in thoery, but I can't tranfer that in code. If you have some idea please help me with some code, cause I'm searching all day long and I found nothing helpful.